# Unexpected Parsing Error On AWS Lambda JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I think this is a syntax error but I'm having trouble finding documentation. I keep getting 'Parsing Error: Unexpected Token {". It says its to do with the 'YesIntent', but won't give specifics. I'm new to JS, but I can't see what could be the problem. Every '{' has a matching '}'.

Any insights would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
const Alexa = require("alexa-sdk");
const appId = ''; //'';

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.appId = appId;
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.execute();
};

const handlers = {
    'LaunchRequest': function() {
      this.emit('YesIntent');
    },

    'YesIntent': function() {
      getData(callback(title) {
        this.response.speak('Here are your data ' + title);
        this.emit(':responseReady');
      }),
    };

function getData() {
  var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region: 'us-west-1'
  });
  var params = {
    TableName: 'WallyFlow_StartTime',
    Key: 'TimeStamp',
  };
  ddb.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err, null);
    } else {
      title = data.Item.title;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: The `YesIntent` function makes no sense. You're calling `getData()` with an argument, but it doesn't take any arguments. And the argument contains invalid syntax, I suspect it's supposed to be an anonymous function, so it should be `function(title)` rather than `callback(title)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, in this style you need more braces :) Updated to:

```
'YesIntent': function () {
    getData( {
    callback(title) {
                this.response.speak('Here are your data ' + title); 
        this.emit(':responseReady'); 
    }})
}};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it should be something like this. `callback` should be the name of the parameter to the `getData()` function, not something you call in the argument. The argument to `getData()` should be a function.

And `getData()` should call the callback function in the non-error case as well as the error case.

You also need an extra `}` to end the `handlers` object, and the end of the statement that calls `getData()` should be `;`, not `,`.

```js
const handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function() {
    this.emit('YesIntent');
  },

  'YesIntent': function() {
    getData(function(title) {
      this.response.speak('Here are your data ' + title);
      this.emit(':responseReady');
    });
  }
};

function getData(callback) {
  var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({
    region: 'us-west-1'
  });
  var params = {
    TableName: 'WallyFlow_StartTime',
    Key: 'TimeStamp',
  };
  ddb.get(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      callback(err, null);
    } else {
      title = data.Item.title;
      callback(title);
    }
  });
}
```